# How to allow html tag in menu?

Tags: 8

How to allow html tag in menu in Drupal 8. For example if use home <sup>@reg</sup> used in menu title it display the html tag.

Answer (score 8):

Following solution works:

```
use Drupal\Core\Render\Markup;

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK()
 */
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_menu(&$variables){
  foreach($variables['items'] as &$link){
    $link['title'] = Markup::create($link['title']);
  }
}
```

Source: [Allow html into menu item names - Solution for Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/theme-development/2007-01-24/how-to-allow-html-into-menu-item-names#comment-11858953)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use a plugin for this. Full tutorial here: [Create a menu link with html markup in drupal 8](https://stefvanlooveren.me/blog/create-menu-link-html-markup-drupal-8)

```
namespace Drupal\MYMODULE\Plugin\Menu;

use Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuLinkDefault;

/**
 * A menu link that displays number of points.
 */
class MyMessagesMenuLink extends MenuLinkDefault {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getTitle() {
    $count = 0;
    if(\Drupal::currentUser()->isAuthenticated()) {
      // Load in your count here
      ...
    }
    return $this->t('My messages <span class="badge badge-dark">@count</span>', ['@count' => $count]);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getCacheMaxAge() {
    return 0;
  }

}
```

Comment: blogs tend to go away, but stackexchange sticks around. Could you copy the best excerpts of the ideas of that blog here?

Comment: Ok, pasted it in the original answer.